# 73 реализованных проектОВ или проектА

Tags: согласование, числительные

Увидел в рекламе фразу:

> 73 реализованных *проектов*

Режет слух, т. к. по аналогии *три проектов* точно не скажешь.

Правильно я понимаю, что корректное согласование с числительным будет:

> 73 реализованных проект**а**

или допустимы оба варианта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: **73 реализованных проекта.**

Числительные два, три, четыре (а также **составные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, например двадцать два)** в именительном падеже сочетаются с существительным в форме родительного падежа и единственного числа, например: двадцать два стола, тридцать три несчастья, пятьдесят четыре человека.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters?id=61